# Angular 5 .subscribe() do not call web api after Insert or Update

Tags: html, angular, visual-studio-2017, observable

I am doing a testing application using `Angular 5` and `Web APi` and `IE 11`. This is an example of `ASP.NET Core 2 and Angular 5 - By Valerio De Sanctis` Book

I have an `HTML` page showing a list of elements using `.subscribe Observable` and a button to call a new page and to create a new ítem. When I create a new item It calls the first HTML Page where it calls again via `.subscribe`  the Web Api to return all ítems including the new one.

when It returns to the first, the Method is called but the Web Api is never called.

```html
import { Component, Inject, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Component({
    selector: "question-list",
    templateUrl: './question-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./question-list.component.css']
})

export class QuestionListComponent implements OnChanges {@Input() quiz: Quiz; questions: Question[]; title: string;
    constructor(private http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: string, private router: Router)
    {
        this.questions = [];
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        if (typeof changes['quiz'] !== "undefined") {

            // retrieve the quiz variable change info
            var change = changes['quiz'];
            // only perform the task if the value has been changed
            if (!change.isFirstChange())
            {
                // execute the Http request and retrieve the result
                this.loadData();
            }
        }
    }

    loadData() {
    //breakpoint
    //first run
        var url = this.baseUrl + "api/question/All/" + 50;
        //second run
         url = this.baseUrl + "api/question/All/" + 51;
        this.http.get<Question[]>(url)
            .subscribe(res => {
                //this.zone.run(() => { // <== added
                    this.questions = res;
                //});
            }, error => console.error(error));
    }
```

Web Api called is inside a `.subscribe`

LoadData() is called when the page is first loaded and it is called again when I return from having inserted the new ítem.

the line

```
this.http.get<Question[]>(url) .subscribe(res => {
```

should make a called to `Question` Controller. But it is never called.

I have tested a little more... I think The problem is that .subscribe() uses the data in cache instead of calling againg the same Web Api with the same `url`.

For instance... the first called I set

```
var url = "http:localhost:8080/" + "api/question/All/" + 50;
```

and in second call i set

```
 var url = "http:localhost:8080/" + "api/question/All/" + 51;
```

it Works fine...

the problem is when i call it twice with the same `Url`

What I am missing?

Comment: are you sure your loadData() method is being called again in the ngChange? Try taking it out of the 2 if statements and see if it actually makes the call to the webserver. Also check what URL its hitting the second time does this.quiz.Id actually have a value? is the url valid? Is there errors in the console?

Comment: thanks.. I refresh the problem...it call he subscribe twice.. but it never call the webapi when it is the same URL... I think it take the data from cache than calling the Web Api.